# How to handle exception in WebAPI in Asp.Net5

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception

I tried handling the exception in webapi service by creating ExceptionAttribute, but looks like I am missing the reference to create the ExceptionFilterAttribute.
I am getting the compiler error "type or namespace name 'HttpActionExecutedContext' could not be found"
Am I missing any reference here? what is the correct way to handle exception in WebAPI in ASP.Net5?
I searched in the internet but couldn't get the specific answer to asp.net5 - WebAPI

the following is the code for creating a ExceptionAttribute

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
   public class ExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            String message = String.Empty;
            var exceptionType = actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetType();

            .....

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
```

instead of

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters;
```

reference
[System.Web.Http.Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters(v=vs.118).aspx)